# How to hot reload/restart when modifying Flutter engine code, or modifying any third party library code?

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging

I am debugging some issues and need to temporarily change Flutter engine's Dart code (e.g. add a few `print`s` to it). I succeeded in doing so months ago, but with Flutter 2.8 I cannot do it. In other words, if I change a few lines of Flutter engine code, and then click "hot reload" or "hot restart", that new code is not deployed.

This also happens when I try to modify third party code from pub dependency.

(Of course, I will not change the code permanently. It is just a debugging approach.)

Thanks for any suggestions!

---

EDIT

Here is details of the settings page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your are using VScode go to file-preferences-settings
search for flutter hot reload and configure it.

And if you have any errors it is not gonna update anything but throw error reports.

Comment: This does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping the debug before you try to reload your code then click the start without debugging. Probably it helps you. Also you can try terminal by writing  "r" to hot reload.

Comment: I even do not enable debugging...